# Seed Rails SQLite Database from a JSON file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to Rails (using 5.0.2). I want to seed my empty SQLite db from a JSON file.

I scaffolded my Product resource, in seed.rb added:

```
records = JSON.parse(File.read('/home/projects/test1/public/products.json'))
records.each do |record|
  ModelName.create!(record)
end
```

Then launched `rake db:seed.`

I got an error:
**rake aborted!
JSON::ParserError: 409: unexpected token at '{**

My JSON consists of products with various properties:

```
    [
  {
    "model": "Brand",
    "brand": "Brand",
    "price": 19.99,
    "currency": "GBP",
    "link1": "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Call-Duty-Ghosts-Hardened-Xbox/dp/B00ECQJ0BS/ref=pd_sim_107_4?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=9GE6A8BW61S1FG4H3ZRJ",
    "link2": "",
    "size1": "{min: "5",max: "90"}",
    "net_weight": "263 kg",
    "size2": "{w: "19.4",h: "11.7",z: "12.7"}",
    "d1": "",
    "color": "['Black','White']",
    "materials": "plastic+concrete, glass ceiling",
    "models": "['model 1',  'model 2',  'model 3', 'model 100']",
    "props": "['prop1',  'Prop1',  'Prop1']",
    "": "",
    "size3": "{w: "100",h: "200",z: "500"}"
  },
  ]
```

How can I fix this JSON file and correctly seed my db with the products data from it?

Is it the best way to import manually created JSON files into Rails, or it's better to try some other approach?

Comment: That is invalid JSON http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `size1`, `size2`, and `size3` properties. For each of those keys, the value contains a double-quote. If you convert those to single quotes or escape them by putting a `\` before them, your JSON should parse correctly.